# NGINX Reverse proxy not forwarding from port 80

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

i have created a simple reverse proxy with NGINX on ubuntu. When I set Nginx to listen on any port that not 80 than i am forwarded to my app that runs on port 4000:

```
server {
  listen       3000;
  server_name  localhost;

      location / {
        proxy_pass http://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }
    }
```

But if I change the listen port to 80  than I always land on NGINX land page instead of being forward to a target IP.

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:4000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

If i run the command ss -ntl i can see that ports 80 and 3000 are open and in use.

Can any one suggest what am i doing wrong?

Comment: running `nginx -T` should show you that the default server is taking precedence

Comment: tnx for the reply @Lawrwnce. how can i change it?

Comment: make your above `default_server` (google it) or unlink the default config from sites-enabled.. `sudo unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

Comment: or make changes to the default config not a new one